# How to use Android to receive on certain radio frequency

Tags: java, c, mobile, android-ndk, telecommunication

Is it possible to write an Android Application to be used on an Android OS Mobile Phone that can RECEIVE (not worried about transmitting) on a frequency between 120-130 MHz range? I've seen an option with an Arduino Board, and also saw something about using the NDK. Would I have to be using a language like C for lower level hardware programming to integrate with the Java parts of the Android Mobile Application? I would prefer to just use the hardware on board with most Smart Phones, specifically a Motorola Droid Bionic.

Comment: You are probably looking for a [software-defined radio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software-defined_radio). These exist, but [not in cellphones, yet](http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/rf-technology-design/sdr/software-defined-radios-tutorial.php). Either that, or a special-purpose receiver, but the Droid Bionic doesn't have one of those.

Comment: Thanks! I just finished digging more. The receiver on most phones, including the Droid 3 and Droid Bionic don't receive on a higher frequency than 108 MHz. I also ended up wiki-ing the software-defined radio deal. Very cool stuff that will hopefully end up coming to our mobile phone technology. I got an FM tuner at http://phandroid.com/2011/09/12/motorola-droid-3-fm-radio-apk-unlocks-droid-bionics-capabilities/ . That's as good as you can get apparently :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks! I just finished digging more. The receiver on most phones, including the Droid 3 and Droid Bionic don't receive on a higher frequency than 108 MHz. I also ended up wiki-ing the software-defined radio deal. Very cool stuff that will hopefully end up coming to our mobile phone technology. I got an FM tuner at phandroid.com/2011/09/12/… . That's as good as you can get apparently :P (You CANNOT choose to recieve on a specific radio frequency on an android phone)